Emojis appearing as chinese symbols when I share to whatsapp from python
I've built a scorecard app where users can share the results of their scores to WhatsApp. I'm trying to use the medal emojis (first place, second place and third place). It works fine when I print to console on PyCharm with my Windows laptop. However, now I've packaged my apk and deployed my app onto my android phone, when I go to share the scorecard to WhatsApp I get chinese symbols in place of my emojis.
I've tried using the unicode for the first place medal ("/U0001F947") and I've also installed the emoji library and done emoji.emojize(':1st_place_medal:'). I also tried the HTML entity (can't remember what it was exactly, something like &#291315) but that just printed out the actual text &#291315
This also happens in Facebook Messenger so it's not a WhatsApp issue
Here is my code:
    def share_app(self):
        from kivy import platform

        emoji_test = "/U0001F947"

        if platform == 'android':
            from jnius import autoclass

            PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
            Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
            String = autoclass('java.lang.String')
            intent = Intent()
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, String('{}'.format(f"{emoji_test}")))
            intent.setType('text/plain')
            chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, String(""))
            PythonActivity.mActivity.startActivity(chooser)


You haven't given examples, so hard to identify what is happening, but as a first guess I suspect that soemwhere UTF-8 encoded text is being treated as UTF-16. So something like "\U0001F947".encode('utf-8').decode('utf-16') gives 鿰螥.

Your code is generating UTF-8 but at some point UTF-16-LE is expected, at client side it is displaying it as UTF-16-LE.

I've edited my question to add in my share_app() function where I'm testing the emoji sharing. Hopefully the addition of my code shows where I'm going wrong?

I found a solution, instead of using the unicode ("/U0001F947") I had to use the Javascript/JSON/Java code "\uD83E\uDD47". Not sure why but the info for all emojis is here: https://emojigraph.org
